# Best way to make a multilingual wp site using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I'm curios about the best way to make a multilingual wp site. For example I want my site to be available in English and French. So far I worked with 2 wordpress installs, but I wonder if there is a way to make a multilingual wp site using just a single wordpress install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a very good way to create multilingual sites with a single WordPress install.

The plugin WPML (WordPress Multilingual) is a very well designed and implemented add-on. It's fairly easy to get started and it makes it really easy to manage two sets of content.

I say it's 'fairly easy' not because the plugin is excessively complex, but because you need to think carefully about how you want to manage your content before you start. However their documentation is pretty good and there are some helpful tips as you go through the settings.

I have no bias to recommend WPML - but I have created numerous commercial sites using it (some with two languages, some in 5 or more).

Let me know if you need more pointers...

Philip

Answer (score 1):

Yah , You can create Multilingual website in single wordpress installation.

---

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multilingual/

  its free and easy to install and use.
- http://wpml.org

  You need to buy this one , but its nice.